# Python heapq implementation

Tags: python

heapq documentation is:

> These two make it possible to view the heap as a regular Python list without surprises: heap[0] is the smallest item, and heap.sort() maintains the heap invariant!

So is heapq implementation really just `heap.sort()` after every push/pop, or is it implemented as a traditional min heap queue (which would make sense, since it would be O(log(n)) instead of O(nlog(n)) for pop and push)?

Comment: did you check this one out? https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

Comment: The push is known as an insertion, and the pop is known as getMin. Check this out, the video in the end is also a good way to understand what's going on: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-heap/

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi yes, the quote is literally from there, that's what caused my confusion. MkWTF - I do know how min heap queue works, I've implemented them myself in C, my question is about exact Python heapq implementation.

Comment: Think of it this way: every sorted list is a valid min-heap, but not every valid min-heap is a sorted list.

Comment: It is implemented as a min heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, heappush() and heappop() in heapq library is definitely O(log(n)).

Secondly, heap.sort() would sort the items in increasing order. Which would mean the min-heap rule that **parent value is always less than the value of children** is still maintained.

heapq implementation is definitely not heap.sort() after every push() and pop() because that would be O(nlog(n)) and suboptimal to the O(log(n)) it provides. For more information take a look at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py